# Trouble Enabling cURL on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, curl

I have installed curl:

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

and I have updated my php.ini file to include:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

I check to see if curl is working with the following command:

```
php -i | grep curl
```

and I receive the following message:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
>   curl

I also tested curl by creating a file called testCurl.php which contains the following:

```
<?php
echo ‘<pre>’;
var_dump(curl_version());
echo ‘</pre>’;
?>
```

When I navigate to localhost/testCurl.php I get an error: HTTP Error 500

Can anyone help me to get curl working?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on server fault?

Comment: Obviously serverfault question.

Comment: `sudo apt-get` with `.dll`? maybe it should be: `extension=curl.so`

Comment: It's okay to ask development environment related questions on SO.

Comment: Should I add this question to server fault for better answers?  Sorry I posted on the wrong site Im very new to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You put the wrong info in your php.ini

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

On Ubuntu/Unix that is

```
extension=php_curl.so
```

`.so` means *Shared Object*, that is a *dynamic library* the error messages speaks of. On Windows that is `.dll`, you probably just mixed that.

And it appears you try to load `sqlite.so` which does not exists. Normally you don't need to change your php.ini file when you install libraries on Ubuntu via apt, because the package scripts take care of that thanks to the work of the package maintainers.

Comment: You should not change it but comment it out. Also remove the other error you have when you startup php. the php5-curl extension configures itself, it should just work. Otherwise you need to learn what's going on. "still does not work" still does not says much. What I answered was more of a comment and some general information. That's all I can say.

Answer (score 1):

If you'r using Ubuntu or have more than one php.ini you may face this problem of enabling extension=php_curl.dll.

It's curious but I was facing this problem using UBUNTU. For some reason it was calling a .dll file, but linux uses .so files.

First thing to do is echo phpinfo(); in a .php file to check what php.ini is getting loaded.

Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/7.1/apache2
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.1/apache2/something/php.ini

So if you change only in one file it may not have the correct effect.

In my case whas in /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini and CURL was calling this way:
;extension=curl.dll

Change to
extension=curl.so

Save and restart apache:
sudo systemctl restart apache2

Answer (score 0):

Support for sqlite2 is removed from php5 I think, so sqlite.so is no longer available in the current version of the package. You can manually restore it from the natty packages (this worked for me):

- Download the old package from here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty-updates/php5-sqlite
- Extracts sqlite.so
- Move sqlite.so (+pdo_sqlite.so) to /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/
- Change file permissions to root:root

(https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-server-bugs/2011-October/065547.html)